# Connect to JIRA using R

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am not able to connect to JIRA using R. Following are the details which might help you to help me.

R version being used:
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Installed package RJDBC. I get following output after loading the library

```
library('RJDBC')
```

> Loading required package: DBI
>   Loading required package: rJava
>   Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘RJDBC’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>   2: package ‘DBI’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>   3: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.3

Installed and loaded cdata

```
library('cdata')
```

> Loading required package: wrapr
>   Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘cdata’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>   2: package ‘wrapr’ was built under R version 3.4.4

How do I remove below error?

```
driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "cdata.jdbc.jira.JiraDriver", classPath = "MyInstallationDir//lib//cdata.jdbc.jira.jar", identifier.quote = "'")
```

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Comment: When you set the `classPath` parameter for the `JDBC` function, are you setting the actual installation directory? Or literally using `MyInstallationDir//lib//...`?

Comment: Agree the directory does not exists. But when I search for "cdata.jdbc.jira.jar" I dont get any file by this name. All these packages are installed in C:\R\win-library\3.4\cdata, etc. Moreover, shouldnt I create jdbc driver, the way we create odbc in windows? Thanks much.

Comment: When you install the JDBC driver, the JAR file should be somewhere on disk. Since you're on Windows, this is likely `C:\Program Files\CData\CData JDBC Driver for Jira 20XX\lib`. You'll initialize the connection (using the connection properties) after you initialize `driver`.

Comment: I dont find any. I just installed RJDBC, nothing else.

Comment: If you wish to use the CData JDBC Driver for Jira, you'll need to download and install. The package you reference is not the same. Download the driver here: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/jira/download/jdbc